# Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component whe i try to navifate after the login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

This error occurs when I try to navigate to dash Page from the loginPage.
This is my loginPage code:

```
export function LoginPage() {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
    const navigate = useNavigate
    const [isPasswordVisible, setIsPasswordVisible] = useState(false);

    const handleLogin = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
           const user = await loginService.login({
              email,
              password
        })
      
        setUser(user)
        console.log(user)

        setEmail('')
        setPassword('')

        navigate('/dash')

    } catch (error) { 
        console.log(error)
    }
      
  }
```

And this is my loginService:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const login = async credentials => {
    const { data } = await axios.post('/login', credentials)
  
    return data
}

export default { login }
```

This is mi AppRouter.js

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

export const AppRouter = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>

            <Route path = '/' element = {<Layout />} >
                <Route index element = {<PublicPage />} />
                <Route path = 'login' element = { <LoginPage />} />
                <Route path = '/dash' element = { <DashLayout />}>
                    <Route index element = { <WellcomePage />} />
                    <Route path = 'users' element = { <UsersPage />} />
                    <Route path = 'newUser' element = { <UserFormPage />} />
                    <Route path = 'users/:id' element = { <UserFormPage />} /> 
                    <Route path = 'posts' element = { <PostsPage />} />
                    <Route path = 'newPost' element = { <PostFormPage />} />
                    <Route path = 'posts/:id' element = { <PostFormPage />} />
               </Route> // End /dash  
          </Route> // End /layout   
          <Route path = '*' element = { <NotFoundPage />} />     

     </Routes>
  )
}
```

Finaly my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
      "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
      "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
      "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
      "axios": "^1.3.4",
      "formik": "^2.2.9",
      "react": "^18.2.0",
      "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
      "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.0",
      "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
      "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2",
      "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
      "react-scroll-to-top": "^3.0.0",
      "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
      "yup": "^1.0.2"
  },
```

I think i have the correct version of react and my hook is declared at the top of the function.

I try to naviate to the protected route dash after login with correct credentials.
can anybody helpme?

Thanks for answering

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: `const navigate = useNavigate()`

Comment: Thank you so match. Solved

Answer (score 1):

in LoginPage Line 6: change `const navigate = useNavigate` to `const navigate = useNavigate();`

Comment: Thank you so match. Solved